# Displaying an image link contained in JSON response from Instagram API?

Tags: java, android, api, instagram, instagram-api

Hey so I am trying to display images in an Android app whos image urls are packaged into a JSON response from the /users/user-id/media/recent Instagram api call.

So here is some example JSON returned by the api call:

```
"images": {
        "low_resolution": {
            "url": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2011/02/02/6ea7baea55774c5e81e7e3e1f6e791a7_6.jpg",
            "width": 306,
            "height": 306
        },
        "thumbnail": {
            "url": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2011/02/02/6ea7baea55774c5e81e7e3e1f6e791a7_5.jpg",
            "width": 150,
            "height": 150
        },
        "standard_resolution": {
            "url": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2011/02/02/6ea7baea55774c5e81e7e3e1f6e791a7_7.jpg",
            "width": 612,
            "height": 612
        }
    },
    "type": "image",
    "users_in_photo": [],
    "filter": "Earlybird",
    "tags": ["foodtruck"],
    "id": "22721881",
```

If however I try and access the image url even in my browser, by pasting the url
         http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2011/02/02/6ea7baea55774c5e81e7e3e1f6e791a7_5.jpg

into the browser, I get the following `Access Denied` response:

```
<Error>
   <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
   <Message>Access Denied</Message>
   <RequestId>39FC127F315ADE6C</RequestId>
   <HostId>
   Kfc/hK1hWuMNh7ESlfEgdHy/ITxF2AVP3AjozUQiDfx2lxS94jTzjfNiZwCSQisH9iuRFY5mI0g=
   </HostId>
</Error>
```

Any ideas why this is the case? The access token I have works fine for api calls themeselves but I cant see how to pass a token for a image request from an image url?

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: interesting, I get different urls in my API response and it works, check on http://gramfeed.com

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass your access token as a parameter according the documentation:

> https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

[Media Endpoints](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/)